# In assembly, the numbers changed when i assigned them to a register

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

I am using visual studio for assembly coding and I am pretty new to assembly. My problem is when I assign a number to a register the value of the number is changed.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO,  dwExitCode:   DWORD
.data
;define your variables here
adword   DWORD ?
aword    WORD 7788h
.code
main PROC
mov   eax,11223344h     ; moved a constant into a register
mov   ebx, eax          ; moved ebx -> eax
mov   adword, eax       ; mov  eax-> adword
mov   ax, aword         ; 7788h -> ax
mov   ah, 10h
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

The value of Eax is not 11223344 it becomes something else.

Comment: Just a guess here, but you may need to set the debug window to display hexadecimal instead of decimal.

Comment: What is "something else" and at what point in execution have you spoted that value?

Comment: how should I set the debug to display hexadecimal?

Comment: instead of 11223344 it gives me 287454020

Comment: Thanks, I found it. I set it to hexadecimal